# React/JS - make entire div clickable but prevent propagation if user clicks on child elements

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I have a parent div which functions as a card containing child elements like images, text and anchor links.

I want the whole div to be clickable, but also allow the user to click on specific links within the div.

Right now I'm using `onClick` for the whole div, and a `Link` (React Router) as a child element. However, when the user clicks on the `Link`, it triggers both the `Link` and the `div`.

I've tried adding an `onClick` method to the `Link` to `stopPropagation` but the `onClick` method never gets triggered. Is there any way around this?

```
interface Props {
  children?: any;
  onClick: () => void;
}

function CardDiv(props: Props) {
  return (
    <div
      onClick={props.onClick}
    >
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
}

export default CardDiv;
```

```
<CardDiv
  className="Card__main"
  onClick={() => {
    console.log("PARENT");
  }}
>
  <Link
    to="https://www.example.com/"
    onClick={(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement, MouseEvent>) =>
      console.log("CHILD");
      event.stopPropagation();
    }
  >
    <b>{props.title}</b>
  </Link>
</CardDiv>
```

The click method in the `Link` never gets called. When I click on the link it takes me to the url, and triggers the parent `onClick` method.

Comment: If you don't prevent the default link action then the link will do what links do... navigate to the target URL path. Are you saying you don't want the link to link to things? Why are you placing interactive elements inside other "interactive" elements? Can you [edit] to include a more complete [mcve] for what you are trying to do?

Comment: @DrewReese As I stated in the title/post, I _do_ want the link to link, I don't want the event to _propagate_ to the parent element. 


When you click on the link specifically - I want it to link. When you click anywhere else on the parent div, I want the onClick event from the parent div to trigger.


Also, plenty of websites have nested interactive elements, it's a fairly common use case. I'm not looking for a different design, I'm looking for a solution for the current design. That's why there is a stopPropagation, but it's not working, that's my whole issue. I updated the code.

Comment: Well, stopping the propagation of the link's click event to the div seems to be the correct logic. If this isn't working as expected then perhaps it's not clear from the code you've provided. Does the `div` element have any clickable area outside the `Link` component? Think you could create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue we could inspect live?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the issue you describe with the code and description provided. Here's a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-js-make-entire-div-clickable-but-prevent-propagation-if-user-clicks-on-c-xq6rl5) you can check. Feel free to fork the sandbox and add more of your real code to see if you can reproduce the issue. If you can reproduce the issue then please share the sandbox so that we can inspect it live.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this could be easily achieved by conditional execution of the onClick function. For example, consider a simpler example below:

```
const handleDivClick = (event) => {
    if (event.target.className === "new") {
        // Clicked on a link within the div, don't trigger the div's onClick
        console.log("I was clicked");
        return;
    }

    // Handle the click on the whole div
    console.log("Div clicked");
};

return (
    <>
            <div onClick={handleDivClick} style={{ border: "2px solid black" }}>
            <h2>Card Title</h2>
            <p>Card content goes here.</p>
            <div className="new">new link</div>
        </div>
    </>
);
```

More elaborating on your code, we can achieve this by setting up some class or id the link, try it out

```
<CardDiv
  className="Card__main"
  onClick={(event) => {
    if(event.target.id==='link')
        return;
    console.log("PARENT");
  }}
>
  <img src="img">whatever</img>
  <Link
    id='link'
    to={link}
  >
    <b>{props.title}</b>
  </Link>
</CardDiv>
```